How to add whitelisted package names in test DPC managed configurations?
I intend to create a whitelist of Android packages that are allowed to be launched on this test device policy controller (DPC) (in admin mode) device.
I intend that only these whitelisted apps shall be launchable and others blocked from even launching/installing from the Play Store. (Similar to iOS bundle ID whitelisting)
What has to be done in managed configurations like some boolean/string to enable it?

"I intend that only these whitelisted apps shall be launchable and others blocked from even launching/installing from play store." I haven't found a way to do this via DPC but Google support has an answer nontheless. There is also this article about the topic. Hope that helps.
